# How do I load Formtastic to test it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I am using Rails 2.0.2 and following Github installation instructions:
1. add as gem source ie "gem sources -a http://gemcutter.org/".....ok
2. install gem ie "gem install formtastic"....gives error, could not find formtastic locally or in a repository
I am learning Ruby on Rails and have no knowledge of gems

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Formtastic will work with Rails 2.0.2. It certainly hasn't been tested for it (from the README):

> I’m only testing Formtastic with the latest Rails 2.4.x stable release, and it should be fine under Rails 2.3.x as well (including nested forms). Patches are welcome to allow backwards compatibility, but I don’t have the energy!

Try upgrading to at least Rails 2.3. And then open your `config/environment.rb` file and add `config.gem formtastic`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I'm using the latest InstantRails release, so looks like I will have to wait for further upgrades or consider installing Rails separately

Comment: You should not be using InstantRails, instead use rubyinstaller.org and install the needed gems manually. InstantRails is ancient! I have a blogpost http://www.dixis.com/?p=117 that describes installing ruby 1.8.7, with a small batchfile to install all common gems. That will get you started in no time.